# Lua string to number - do not use e notation

Tags: lua

I have a string represent a big number, no more than 19 digits, something like "3435939477110523131", I'd like to convert it from string to number and convert it back.
But when I am using tonumber() it converts with E notation, which is very stupid.

```
Lua 5.1.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2008 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> a = "3435939477110523131"
> print(tonumber(a))
3.4359394771105e+18
```

It loses some digits. Is there a way to convert it to a full number without e notation?

Comment: Lua 5.1 numbers are `double` (max integer value is `2^53` which is less than `10^16`), to print them exactly use `print(("%.f"):format(n))`

Comment: Lua 5.3+ integers are up to `2^63` (19 digits)

Comment: There is [lmapm](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lmapm), which supports arbitrary precision numbers, if that's what you are looking for.

Comment: @PaulKulchenko, also [limath](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#limath) if only integers are needed.

Answer (score 2):

`"3435939477110523131"` is to large to accurately store in lua 5.1

We can see this by doing:

```lua
local a = "3435939477110523131"
local ourNumber = tonumber(a)
local computersNumber = 3435939477110522900 --this is the number `a` ends up as.

print(ourNumber == computersNumber)
```

in lua 5.1 this will print true, the max integer you can store accurately in lua 5.1 is `2^53 - 1`, which is `9007199254740991`

---

print will attempt to convert its arguments to strings, for a number this results in scientific notation and you don't capture all the precision.

You can prevent this by converting the value to a string for print using `string.format`

```lua
str = "3435939477110523131"
num = tonumber(str)

print(str, num, string.format("%.f",num))
```

---

In version 5.3 if you use `string.format` with `"%.f"` you will get an incorrect result, instead use `tostring` or `"%.i"`

```
str = "3435939477110523131"
num = tonumber(str)

print(str, num, tostring(num), string.format("%.i",num), string.format("%.f",num))
```